# Problem with tags in Django | used taggit for storing tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-taggit

Template file:

```
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade show p-0">
 {% for event in events %}
 {% for tag in event.tags.all %}
 {% if tag == 'Tech' %}
   <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col mb-5">
     <div class="d-flex h-100">
      <div class="flex-shrink-0">
       <img class="img-fluid" src="{{event.e_image.url}}" alt="" style="width: 430px; height: 350px;">
       <h4 class="bg-dark text-primary p-2 m-0">{{event.e_date}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-start bg-secondary border-inner px-4">
      <h5 class="text-uppercase">{{event.e_name}}</h5>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}        
</div>
```

```py
class Events(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    e_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='eventimg')
    e_date = models.DateTimeField()
    e_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.e_name
```

**When I try {% if tag == 'Tech'%} to display block only when tag is equal to Tech then its not workin. I mean that Block is not at all visible.
There are multiple tags in a single event thus I am looping event.tags.all**

I already had installed, imported and mentioned taggit in settings, its working properly. But I am stucked in above situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [GitHub](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/blob/8dc5ab0e84b46399d948ebd17dd7c293dc9a1b82/taggit/models.py#L19O) code, there is a `name` field so it should be `{% if tag.name == 'Tech' %}` instead, like so:

```html
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade show p-0">
 {% for event in events %}
 {% for tag in event.tags.all %}
 {% if tag.name == 'Tech' %}
   <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col mb-5">
     <div class="d-flex h-100">
      <div class="flex-shrink-0">
       <img class="img-fluid" src="{{event.e_image.url}}" alt="" style="width: 430px; height: 350px;">
       <h4 class="bg-dark text-primary p-2 m-0">{{event.e_date}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-start bg-secondary border-inner px-4">
      <h5 class="text-uppercase">{{event.e_name}}</h5>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}        
</div>
```

The `tag` is an instance of the `Tag` model, so you should not compare it directly with string.